# How to fix CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH?

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I am trying to use CUBLAS to perform a simple matrix multiplication. I am using the following function

```
#ifdef CUBLAS_API_H_
// cuBLAS API errors
static const char *_cudaGetErrorEnum(cublasStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}
#endif
void gpu_blas_mmul(cublasHandle_t &handle, cudaStream_t &stream, const real_t *A, const real_t *B, real_t *C, const int m, const int k, const int n) {
    int lda=m,ldb=k,ldc=m;
    const real_t alf = 1;
    const real_t bet = 0;
    const real_t *alpha = &alf;
    const real_t *beta = &bet;

    cublasSetStream(handle, stream);
    // Do the actual multiplication
    cublasStatus_t err = GEMM(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, n, k, alpha, A, lda, B, ldb, beta, C, ldc);
    if(err!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"CUBLAS err : "<<_cudaGetErrorEnum(err)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

In a header file, GEMM is defined as
    #define GEMM cublasDgemm
    #define real_t double

The function is called like this:

```
gpu_blas_mmul(cublas[i], streams[P/2-i-1], A, B, C, N, N, N);
```

***A***, ***B*** and ***C*** are device memory locations and I am trying to multiply two NxN matrices (both stored in column-major format). 
***streams*** is a P/2 length array of CUDA Streams and ***cublas*** is an array of CUBLAS handles and ***i*** counts up from 0 to P/2-1. Both arrays contain valid handles and streams respectively (no errors when creating them). I am compiling the code for sm2.0. So double-precision shouldn't be a problem.

The code works fine when called from one file. This section has its own cublasCreate and cublasDestroy calls. The same function when called from another location throws the error "CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH".

What could be wrong?

### Thank you,

Thomas

Comment: Can you provide a complete, compilable code that reproduces the issue?  What GPU are you running on?  What is the CUDA version? Is this windows or linux?

Comment: Ah well ... I finally figured it out. The streams and handles were in fact invalid. Something as simple as the array index going out of bounds.

Oh well! I feel stupid now!

Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Please either post an answer explaining what you did to fix it (I will upvote it), or else delete the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I WAS using invalid CUDA stream and/or CUBLAS handles. I was overrunning array bounds (the arrays storing the CUDA streams and CUBLAS handles)

The cryptic error message gave me no idea as to what was happening. However, starting from a basic example again and working up led me to finding the issue.

Hope someone finds this helpful! :)